# Embed html class into my page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The landing page of reliefweb has a 'latest disasters' section that I want to embed onto my website (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0zyi.jpg)).

I was told that I need to use an iframe and some JavaScript to get the element with class=“latest-disasters”.

This way, when the block is updated, it will also reflect on my website.

As I have no background in JavaScript, can someone show me how to do this?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information.
But this is usually how it's done with iframe

```
<iframe src="http://www.latest-disasters-api.com" class = "latest-disasters"></iframe>
```

About the javascript part i don't have enough information but obviously you need some kind of SDK or JavaScript plugin

Hope it will help

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Javascript,. Can you tell me what information you need?